# If statements to test if a variable is in range

Tags: windows, vb.net, visual-studio, console

I am making a program to calculate grades.
My patricipation score is based off how many days of class you missed.

Here is what i want to program.

I saved my days missed as AB1 as deemed by user input.

Then, AB2 is supposed to be my patricipation score

Patricipation score is based on 100 points
If you miss 2 classes, then you have 100 points.
Then, for each day after the 2 you miss you lose 20 points. You cant go negative in points either.
So here is what i want to say.

if you miss 2 or less days. your participation score is 100.
if you miss between 3 and 6 days your score is either 80,60,40,20
if you miss 7 or more your score is 0.

```
 Sub Main()
    Dim TG1 As Integer = -1
    While TG1 < 0 Or TG1 > 200
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your grade for project #1 <0-200>: ")
        TG1 = Console.ReadLine()
    End While

    Dim TG2 As Integer = -1
    While TG2 < 0 Or TG2 > 200
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your grade for project #2 <0-200>: ")
        TG2 = Console.ReadLine()
    End While

    Dim TG3 As Integer = -1
    While TG3 < 0 Or TG3 > 200
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your grade for project #3 <0-200>: ")
        TG3 = Console.ReadLine()
    End While

    Dim MT1 As Integer = -1
    While MT1 < 0 Or MT1 > 150
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your grade on the midterm <0-150>: ")
        MT1 = Console.ReadLine()
    End While

    Dim AB1 As Integer = -1
    While AB1 < 0 Or AB1 > 30
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter how much you were absent   <0-30>: ")
        AB1 = Console.ReadLine()
    End While

    Dim AB2 As Integer
    If AB1 <= 2 Then AB2 = 100
    If 2 < AB1 < 8 Then AB2 = 100 - ((AB1 - 2) * 20)
    If AB1 > 7 Then AB2 = 0

    Dim GSF As Integer
    GSF = TG1 + TG2 + TG3 + MT1 + AB2

    Dim PNA As Integer
    PNA = 900 - GSF

    Dim PeNA As Integer
    PeNA = PNA / 150



    Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------")
    Console.WriteLine("--GRADE SUMMARY--")
    Console.WriteLine("Project #1    : {0}", TG1)
    Console.WriteLine("Project #2    : {0}", TG2)
    Console.WriteLine("Project #3    : {0}", TG3)
    Console.WriteLine("Midterm Exam  : {0}", MT1)
    Console.WriteLine("Participation : {0}", AB2)
    Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------")
    Console.WriteLine("Total grade so far: {0}", GSF)
    Console.WriteLine("")
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", "Desired grade".PadRight(20), "Points needed".PadRight(20), "Percentage needed on final")
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", "A".PadRight(20), PNA.ToString.PadRight(20), PeNA.ToString.PadRight(20))


    'A - 900-1000
    'B - 800-899
    'C - 700-799
    'D - 600-699
```

Comment: so what's your question?

Comment: How come my if statements for AB2 are giving me weird results.

Comment: If AB1 <= 2 Then AB2 = 100
    If 2 < AB1 < 8 Then AB2 = 100 - ((AB1 - 2) * 20)
    If AB1 > 7 Then AB2 = 0

Comment: @user2860326: Define "weird results."  When you step through this in a debugger, on what line does the value change in an unexpected way?

Comment: so lets say i enter 1 for "how many days did you miss"

Comment: It shows participation at 120

Comment: participation points are my AB2 variable

Comment: What do you suggest I enter in there?

Comment: I need to change my AB2 conditionals to something that works showing 2 or less days missed, coming up to 100 points. Then if the user enter a number between 3 and 7, it shows 20 points missed for the days after the 2. Then anything beyond that showing as 0 points in participation

Comment: I'd worry about your own grades, this looks like it was developed for a spreadsheet, in which case it would make sense. MT1 = GetValueFromUser("Please enter your grade on the midterm",0,150)

Answer (score 1):

```
If 2 < AB1 < 8 Then
```

probably doesnt do what you think. it probably should be

```
 IF 2 < AB1 ANDALSO AB1 < 8 THEN...
```

Comment: is the first statement even possible in visual basic if so what does it actually do?

Comment: I think it always returns true

Comment: Great works fantastic, I was struggling hard with this. I appreciate it!

Comment: It must always return true, because every statement that was below 2 was returning to that if statement.

Comment: click the check if it helped